# Setting up Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server

I used to have an Ubuntu 10.04 system that was configured to act as a DHCP server for a local network and as a gateway for computers on the local network to access the internet, so it had two ethernet cards, one for the local network and one connected to the internet.

I've just built a new server and installed 18.04 on it but for the life of me I can't remember how I set up old server. I know I used dnsmasq to provide the DHCP for the local network but I don't know how I set up the forwarding of internet traffic - I know I didn't do anything with iptables. The network thing did work for a day as I wanted, after installing dnsmasq, but now it's not working - DNS lookups seem to work, but pings and HTTP don't work - so I can't view web pages.

So, to clarify, system looks like:-

```
PCs (windows / ubuntu) / Printers ----- Ubuntu Server ---- Internet
```

I used to be able to view web sites on the internet from the PCs, but now, with the 18.04 I can't (but it did for a day or so).

What have I done and how can I fix it to make it work like before?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple thing in the end, the system wasn't set up to forward IP traffic! To enable it:-

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and that was all that was needed.